# Adding a BottomNavigationBar to multiple activities without code duplication - use fragments?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Currently trying to implement a BottomNavigationBar from the Android Support Library in an application with 4 top level activities, but unable to make it appear in all Activities without just copy-pasting my XML.

I have the following in my Main Activity;

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
        design:itemBackground="@color/menuGreen"
        design:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        design:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

And this appears OK, but it feels like bad design to just copy it into my other Activities. I tried creating a separate xml file for it and adding it to other actiivites with an  tag, but this still required copy-pasting the layout code (which I assume is bad?)

Should this be included as a fragment, so the application logic can be only written once and it can be added to all activities? Or should I only use one activity and have the navigation bar swap between fragments in that one activity?

Comment: I advise you look into [this](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0). You should think of the [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) as a widget, enabling and disabling items in your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only one activity and when the items of a bottom navigation view are clicked u can open the view in a fragment or in a viewpager accoroding to your need.Here is a simple example of usage of bottom navigation view
http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use one activity and fragments for bottom navigation.
If you need help implementing this, I can provide you some code.

Answer (score 0):

> Use FrameLayout in your main Activity and onClick of Bottom navigation menu change fragments